# Angular Reactive Form, valueChanges runs into "maximum call stack size"

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, onchange, reactive

I am trying to change my formarray values based on the index as soon as a change in the form occurs.
The following situation is given:
I have given phases each with a start and end date. Except for the first phase, the start date of a phase should always be the same as the end date of the previous phase.

I think the error occurs because the valueChanges always calls itself as the value of the form is changed at the end of the method.

```
  onChanges() {
this.projectForm.controls['phases'].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  for (var i = 1; i <= this.phasecount; i++) {
      this.projectPhases.at(i).patchValue({ pStart: value[i - 1].pEnd });                   
  }
})
```

}

do any of you have an idea how to work around the error (maybe a termination condition)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How often is onChanges called here..? Just once I hope?

Comment: Hey, only once in the NgOnInit-function

Comment: You can try to add {emitEvent: false, onlySelf:true} as options for the patchValue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `this.projectPhases.at(i).patchValue({ pStart: value[i - 1].pEnd });` triggers this event `this.projectForm.controls['phases'].valueChanges` and it infinite loops.

You could set `emitEvent` option to `false` while doing patchValue :

```js
this.projectPhases.at(i)
.patchValue({ pStart: value[i - 1].pEnd }, { emitEvent: false });
```

Comment: thanks alot, no maximum call stack size anymore :). But im now getting the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'patchValue' of undefined.

Comment: This is probably because somehow you get into a state where `this.projectPhases.at(i)` is undefined, you should probably debug this line of code until you get into this case.

Comment: nevermind, i had to put < into the for-loop not <=